# Get the total time spent working on a file

Tags: workflow

I'm working on commissions and it would be wonderful to know how much time I spend with each file. Not because I charge per hour (yet), I'm merely curious.

It would be nice to track how many minutes with activity each file has (simply having it open in blender shouldn't count). It should be totally automatic.

Does anyone know of such a plugin or a way to go about doing this inside Blender?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic as this isn't something that should be done from within Blender. There are existing tools available for monitoring the filesystem, try over at [superuser](http://superuser.com/) or [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: I disagree (surprise!). Why shouldn't it be done from within blender? It is blender that knows if I am actively working with a file or merely waiting for a render to complete. It is blender that knows if I move my mouse, editing objects or attend a meeting and just letting blender be open.

Comment: Files access and writes, along with info on the process, user input, etc, are all available at a higher level and (like I said) there are tools to record these kinds of statistics. Implementing within Blender adds needless complexity. Anyhow, it seems you have found something your happy with below, so it's all good. ;)

Comment: It's bizarre to say this "shouldn't" be done in Blender. Can it _not_ be done from a technical standpoint? That would be different.  Without even looking into it I know it could be done by simply using the builtin Python API to look at the current file and count how many seconds it has been open. From memory, one could probably make a handler that updates the addon context whenever the user interacts with Blender. In fact, it would probably be more difficult to get activity info (requirement of OP) from outside Blender, so if anything you _should_ say it shouldn't be done _outside_ Blender. Oo

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's an addon that keeps track of the actual time you spent working on the project.

[image: screenshot of project timer addon]

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/System/Project_Timer

> The time spent working in the blend file is recorded, and stored in
> the blend to continue from the next time it is opened.
>
> If you stop work for longer than 30 seconds, the timer stops counting
> and reverts back to the time of your last action, minimizing idle
> time.

Edit: Download link seems to no longer work, here's the last version of the add-on I could find: [Download](http://gregzaal.com/files/system_project_timer.zip) (unzip, install py file).

Updated version for Blender 2.80+: https://github.com/uhlik/bpy/blob/master/system_time_tracker.py
Courtesy of @iFarbod

Comment: This addon seems to be gone.

Comment: I still have it installed so uploaded it myself and edited answer with link.

Comment: Is there a version of this for Blender 2.9?

Comment: @Alex updated version for 2.80+ https://github.com/uhlik/bpy/blob/master/system_time_tracker.py

Comment: I updated the addon to Blender 3 and created a github repo: https://github.com/theres1/Project-Timer

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: An addon already exist. Check this link : https://projects.blender.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=467&aid=35700&group_id=153
Thank's to [Greg Zaal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/9/greg-zaal) for giving the link :)

You can try to write a little python script which you are going to execute twice: when you open your file and when you'll close it.

My idea is to store the time at which you started your blender file and the time at which you close it.

For calculate the time you can use the time library and the time.time wich give you the time in second since the 1st january 1970:

```
import time

start_time = time.time()
end_time = start_time - time.time()
# end_time gonna give you the time between sartTime and end_time
```

Now if you want to store your time in a file with python you can use the pickle library. Here I show you how to store and re-use an object stored in a file:

```
import pickle
import time

start_time = time.time()

with open("my_time.txt", "wb") as starting_time:  # open the file in write mode
    my_pickler = pickle.Pickler(start_time)
    my_pickler.dump(start_time)  # put start_time in the my_time.txt file
# now we have stored an object in a file we are going to open a file to recover an object

with open("my_time.txt", "rb") as starting_time:  # open the file in read mode 
    my_pickler = pickle.Unpickler(start_time)
    recover_time = my_unpickler.load()  # put the contenent of my_time.txt in recover_time
```

/!\ you file are saved in the blender directories

Hope it can help. If you want I can try to write this little script for you.

Comment: Why are you pickling it instead of just dumping the int value of seconds?

Comment: I use the pickler for saving the value of second the first time you use the script (when you open blender) and re-use it after when you run the script before closing blender for calculate the final time. I know that you can use other solution but I took the habit of the pickler because of other python project where I had a lot of object to save and recover later.

Comment: I get the concept of persistence but it seems like a waste of memory and time to pickle a whole object just to store an int... why not just write the int value itself to a file?

Comment: There's a nice simple addon I use all the time that does exactly this: https://projects.blender.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=467&aid=35700&group_id=153

Comment: Thanks for both the suggestion and the link. Will check it out.

Comment: @GregZaal That was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: This answer has already been edited with the link, so would be redundant

Answer (score 2):

In case if someone else is still strugling. There's Martin Zielinski's original addon (https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/System/Project_Timer/) upgraded to Blender 3.0: https://github.com/theres1/Project-Timer

Cheers!