# Track Time Spent Working on a File (Blender 2.9)

Tags: workflow

I was looking for addons/methods for tracking time while working in a .blend file. I found [this question already answered](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2646/get-the-total-time-spent-working-on-a-file), but it links to a really outdated addon.

Is there anything like the following description that works for Blender 2.9?

> The time spent working in the blend file is recorded, and stored in
> the blend to continue from the next time it is opened.
>
> If you stop work for longer than 30 seconds, the timer stops counting
> and reverts back to the time of your last action, minimizing idle
> time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Project Timer](https://developer.blender.org/T35700) addon in the linked question got updates. They are a bit hidden in the comments. The latest version [system_project_timer_2_8_update_4.py](https://dev-files.blender.org/file/download/yjbojcpxeucpipasdcez/PHID-FILE-iip5wnarwsjizb2hiorp/system_project_timer_2_8_update_4.py) works for Blender 3.0.

After installing the addon, the tracked project time is displayed in the header of the *Info* window. Just split one window and choose editor type *Info*. It tracks the mouse movement and stops the time if you don't move the mouse for 30 seconds.

[image]